# How to enable bootstrap popover to open and close multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want a popover using bootstrap that can be closed through clicking on a button within the popup. But I after closing, I have to click twice on the button to open the popover again.

I currently have the following implementation:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="example" class="btn btn-primary">example</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: 'true',
        title : '<span class="text-info"><strong>Title</strong></span>'+
                '<button type="button" id="close" class="close"
                 onclick="$(&quot;#example&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);
                 ">&times;</button>',
        content : 'Content'
    });
});
```

How can I implement a close-button in the popover without having to click twice on the button to re-open the popover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by adding `click()` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: 'true',
        title : '<span class="text-info"><strong>Title</strong></span>'+
                '<button type="button" id="close" class="close"
                 onclick="$(&quot;#example&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;).click();
                 ">&times;</button>',
        content : 'Content'
    });
});
```